# Concat React state value with HTML tag

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have state with html tag value. I want `concat` previous value with new data from `API` with looping. But i get value like this

> [object Object][object Object],[object Object][object Object]

This my code :

```
for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    const dataYesterday = await data[i].map((data,i) => {
    if(i === 0){
        return(
            <div>
                <div className="dashboard">
                    <h1>
                        <i className="fa fa-calendar-o fa-lg mr-7"/>  Pemenang Hari ke {i} 
                    </h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
})
await this.setState({dataLeaderboard : this.state.dataLeaderboard + dataYesterday})
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concatenating will convert them to strings, which will throw away all the useful data in them (as you've already discovered).

You should use JSX. e.g.:

```
<React.Fragment>
    {this.state.dataLeaderboard}
    {dataYesterday}
</React.Fragment>
```

Comment: Where you are currently trying to concatinate

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add the items of one array to another array, you can use

```
firstArray.concat(secondArray)
```

Code:

```
for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
  const dataYesterday = await data[i].map((data,i) => {
    if(i === 0){
        return(
            <div>
                <div className="dashboard">
                    <h1>
                        <i className="fa fa-calendar-o fa-lg mr-7"/>  Pemenang Hari ke {i} 
                    </h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
  })
  await this.setState({dataLeaderboard : this.state.dataLeaderboard.concat(dataYesterday)})
}
```

The concat() method is used to merge two or more arrays. This method does not change the existing arrays, but instead returns a new array.